# How to put different images for each listitem in android?

Tags: android

In my project I need to create Listview. I have created row.xml for the textview and imageview to display in listitems. I have mentioned those list item names in strings.xml file. But **how can I mention the images in the strings.xml file.** How could I do that.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Add Integer-Array with Image resource ids..

Comment: Please can you give an example for that?

Answer (score 2):

Take an array of images with resourceIds and set the imageview's background where you are inserting the value in textviews get the image from the arrays of imageIds. You dont need to put the image or anything in **strings.xml**. Try this [link](http://android.modaco.com/topic/315461-how-to-update-custom-listview-images/)

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter,you can explicitly set the images to the ImageView of each item.You can either set using if-else if-else depending on the position if you have few items to be displayed everytime.or you can set a array and set images accordingly for large number of items.

Answer (score 0):

By simply get use this following code..

```
   Resources res = getResources();
   TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
   Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);//0 is index of your icons array

 <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/icon1</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon2</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon3</item>

    </array>
```

You are also use [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray) . There see the example of typed Array.

please sure that images lenth and string_array length should be equal,because of i am not put failure conditions .

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);


        String[] str=res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array);

        list.setAdapter(new Adapter(this,icons,str));

        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"You are clicked at:"+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    class Adapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        TypedArray icons;
        String[] str;
        public Adapter(Context mContext, TypedArray icons,String[] str) 
        {
            this.context= mContext;
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.icons=icons;
            this.str=str;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return icons.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            final MainListHolder mHolder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                mHolder = new MainListHolder();
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_layout, null);
                mHolder.mTextview=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                mHolder.imageView=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                v.setTag(mHolder);
            } 
            else
            {
                mHolder = (MainListHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            mHolder.mTextview.setText(str[pos]);
            Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(pos);//0 is index of your icons array
            mHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);//Your Drawables array
            return v;
        }
        class MainListHolder 
        {

            private ImageView imageView;
            private TextView mTextview;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.app1);
        Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0); I gave like this in my java file but it is not detecting the array...Wat to do plz help me

Comment: I have check it like this...It works for me By set simple image.. ImageView im=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       im.setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: Hi sorry I created images.xml in values folder and in that I have defined the array..But now I have defined in arrays.xml and it didnt showed any error

Comment: Can you tell me how to keep those imgs to list items? I have used switch case but it is showing error..

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(null);  
switch(position) {case 0: myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageUSA-FLAG);
         break;
case 1: myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageUK-FLAG);
         break;}
return myImageView;}

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
switch( position ){ case 0:Intent newActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), abc.class);startActivity(newActivity);
break; case 1:Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),friend.class);startActivity(newActivity1);               break;...

Comment: Hi in my arrayadapter can we give 3 parameters like this ArrayAdapter<Array> ad1 = new ArrayAdapter<Array>(this,R.layout.rowinfo,icons);....when i am giving that statement it is showing erro...how to declare that...plz let me know